# Getting the <link> attribute in HTML using BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been scraping the Google News RSS feed for a project and I need the `link` attribute of the HTML code. This is what I've tried so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"
}


URL = f"https://news.google.com/rss/search?q={'Apple'}&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en"
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all("link"))
```

[image: The structure of the RSS feed]

But after I execute the above code, I get this result where the `link` tags are empty:

```
[<link/>, <link/>, <link/>, <link/>, <link/>, <link/>, <link/>, <link/>, <link/>,...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would install `lxml`:

```
pip install lxml
```

Then use the `xml` parser as RSS is XML not HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"
}

URL = f"https://news.google.com/rss/search?q={'Apple'}&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en"
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'xml')
print(soup.find_all("link"))
```

Then you should get this (truncated):

```
[<link>https://news.google.com/search?q=Apple&amp;hl=en-US&amp;gl=US&amp;ceid=US:en</link>, <link>https://www.macrumors.com/2021/02/23/apple-pay-launches-in-mexico/</link>, <link>https://www.macrumors.com/2021/02/22/refurbished-m1-13-inch-macbook-pro/</link>, ...]
```